# NFT from custom ERC-1155 smart contract not displaying correctly on Etherscan for Goerli test net

Tags: ethereum, nft, etherscan

I have deployed an ERC-1155 smart contract to the Goerli test net at address: 0xE4e0b1FA4b3f4B947A14D429962eD30fEc9b9a96 ([Etherscan link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0xE4e0b1FA4b3f4B947A14D429962eD30fEc9b9a96))

I performed the first transaction on the smart contract, which transferred an NFT to this address: 0x771d8Ef1FA5b7fDE4cBd88925F21cF97D8b8A46D ([Etherscan link](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x771d8ef1fa5b7fde4cbd88925f21cf97d8b8a46d)).

If I open the ERC1155 Token Txns tab on Etherscan, I see the tokens in my account, however, I do not see a View NFT button next to the token, which is what I see if I were to purchase an NFT from OpenSea.

For context, this is what I would see in Etherscan for an NFT from OpenSea, with the View NFT button:

[image]

Here is the URI pointing to the token's metadata on IPFS: https://bafyreige3aa4bqeoy52rswmpkhzrlpitpvsyfp5hpusfuq52wdybuyerfi.ipfs.dweb.link/metadata.json

And here is the token's metadata:

```
{"name":"Goerli test 6","description":"","image":"https://bafkreidkn5flzjnvcdginsktvzbcrslqd7wrabjavejectvqxi2xq5v6bm.ipfs.dweb.link/"}
```

Is there anything in particular that must be done on my part so that Etherscan can preview the NFT? Or is it more likely that my smart contract or the metadata format is incorrect?

Answer (score -2):

Your code needs to be published on Etherscan first.

Comment: Your earlier post was deleted by a moderator because it is not an answer.